# Python Plotly Subplots Axis Prefix

Tags: python, plotly

I want the currency sign as a prefix to the x-axis in a plotly subplot, the commands are fine because it works elsewhere but it just seems to play up when it integrates with the subplot functions.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import random

x = np.array(["France", "Spain", "Italy", "Chile"])

df = pd.DataFrame({"country": np.repeat(x, [10,10,10,10]).tolist(),
                       "rating": random.sample(range(0,100),40),
                      "price": random.sample(range(100,1000),40)})

scatter = make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 2, shared_yaxes = True, shared_xaxes = True,
                        
                   subplot_titles = ("France", "Spain", "Italy", "Chile"),
                        x_title = "Price", y_title = "Rating"
                   )

scatter.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.loc[df["country"]=="France", "price"],
                            y = df.loc[df["country"]=="France", "rating"],
                            mode = "markers"),
                            row = 1, col = 1)

scatter.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.loc[df["country"]=="Spain", "price"],
                            y = df.loc[df["country"]=="Spain", "rating"],
                            mode = "markers"),
                            row = 1, col = 2)

scatter.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.loc[df["country"]=="Italy", "price"],
                            y = df.loc[df["country"]=="Italy", "rating"],
                            mode = "markers"),
                            row = 2, col = 1)

scatter.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.loc[df["country"]=="Chile", "price"],
                            y = df.loc[df["country"]=="Chile", "rating"],
                            mode = "markers"),
                            row = 2, col = 2)

scatter.update_layout(showlegend = False, plot_bgcolor = "white",
                     xaxis = dict(showtickprefix = "all", tickprefix = "£"))

scatter.show()
```

If I remove the shared x and y axes commands then the currency will appear only on the bottom left subplot but I don't want to remove this really.

Does anyone know any way around this, please?

Update

I'm currently creating the following graph:
[image]

and I want to be able to create the following:
[image]

Comment: Could you add a photo of the plot in both cases? This would help me understand the issue better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out how to do it, you need to update the subplots individually with the code
`xaxisN_tickprefix = "£"` with 'N' being the plot number of the graph. In this case I was trying to update plots 3 and 4, full code and graphs below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import random

x = np.array(["France", "Spain", "Italy", "Chile"])

df = pd.DataFrame({"country": np.repeat(x, [10,10,10,10]).tolist(),
                       "rating": random.sample(range(0,100),40),
                      "price": random.sample(range(100,1000),40)})

scatter = make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 2, shared_yaxes = True, shared_xaxes = True,
                        
                   subplot_titles = ("France", "Spain", "Italy", "Chile"),
                        x_title = "Price", y_title = "Rating"
                   )

scatter.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.loc[df["country"]=="France", "price"],
                            y = df.loc[df["country"]=="France", "rating"],
                            mode = "markers"),
                            row = 1, col = 1)

scatter.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.loc[df["country"]=="Spain", "price"],
                            y = df.loc[df["country"]=="Spain", "rating"],
                            mode = "markers"),
                            row = 1, col = 2)

scatter.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.loc[df["country"]=="Italy", "price"],
                            y = df.loc[df["country"]=="Italy", "rating"],
                            mode = "markers"),
                            row = 2, col = 1)

scatter.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.loc[df["country"]=="Chile", "price"],
                            y = df.loc[df["country"]=="Chile", "rating"],
                            mode = "markers"),
                            row = 2, col = 2)

scatter.update_layout(showlegend = False, plot_bgcolor = "white",
                     #xaxis = dict(showtickprefix = "all", tickprefix = "£")  <- old code
                     xaxis3_tickprefix = "£", xaxis4_tickprefix = "£") #new code

scatter.update_xaxes(range = [0,1000]) #also added to ensure the axis align
scatter.update_yaxes(range = [0,100]) #also added to ensure the axis align

scatter.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is pretty similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63127031/annotations-varying-by-subplot-with-plotly-express/63137444#63137444) The idea is to update every single trace using `for_each_xaxis` and `for_each_yaxis` as following.

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import random

x = np.array(["France", "Spain", "Italy", "Chile"])

df = pd.DataFrame({"country": np.repeat(x, [10,10,10,10]).tolist(),
                       "rating": random.sample(range(0,100),40),
                      "price": random.sample(range(100,1000),40)})
```

## Plot

```py
scatter = make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 2,
                        shared_yaxes = True, shared_xaxes = True,
                        subplot_titles = ("France", "Spain", "Italy", "Chile"),
                        x_title = "Price", y_title = "Rating")

scatter.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.loc[df["country"]=="France", "price"],
                            y = df.loc[df["country"]=="France", "rating"],
                            mode = "markers"),
                            row = 1, col = 1)

scatter.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.loc[df["country"]=="Spain", "price"],
                            y = df.loc[df["country"]=="Spain", "rating"],
                            mode = "markers"),
                            row = 1, col = 2)

scatter.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.loc[df["country"]=="Italy", "price"],
                            y = df.loc[df["country"]=="Italy", "rating"],
                            mode = "markers"),
                            row = 2, col = 1)

scatter.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.loc[df["country"]=="Chile", "price"],
                            y = df.loc[df["country"]=="Chile", "rating"],
                            mode = "markers"),
                            row = 2, col = 2)

# New stuff from here
scatter = scatter.update_layout(showlegend = False, plot_bgcolor = "white")

def update_y(y):
    y.update(matches=None)
    y.showticklabels=True
    
def update_x(x):
    x.update(matches=None)
    x.showticklabels=True
    x.tickprefix = "£"
    
scatter.for_each_yaxis(update_y)
scatter.for_each_xaxis(update_x)
```

[image]

## Using `plotly.express`

If you like you could eventually use plotly express but in this case you need to deal with annotations too.

```py
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(
           df,
           x="price",
           y="rating",
           color="country",
           facet_col="country",
           facet_col_wrap=2,
           facet_row_spacing=0.2, # default is 0.07 when facet_col_wrap is used
           facet_col_spacing=0.04, # default is 0.03
           )

fig = fig.update_layout(showlegend = False, plot_bgcolor = "white")
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=a.text.split("=")[-1]))

def update_y(y):
    y.update(matches=None)
    y.showticklabels=True
    y.title.text = ""
    
def update_x(x):
    x.update(matches=None)
    x.showticklabels=True
    x.tickprefix = "£"
    x.title.text = ""


fig.for_each_yaxis(update_y)
fig.for_each_xaxis(update_x)

extra_annotations =[
        go.layout.Annotation(
            {
                'showarrow': False,
                'text': 'Price',
                'x': 0.5,
                'xanchor': 'center',
                'xref': 'paper',
                'y': 0,
                'yanchor': 'top',
                'yref': 'paper',
                'yshift': -30,
                'font': dict(
                    # family="Courier New, monospace",
                    size=16,
                    # color="#ffffff"
                    ),

            }),
         go.layout.Annotation(
            {
                'showarrow': False,
                'text': 'Rating',
                'x': 0,
                'xanchor': 'center',
                'xref': 'paper',
                'y': 0.7,
                'yanchor': 'top',
                'yref': 'paper',
                'xshift': -40,
                'textangle': -90,
                'font': dict(
                    # family="Courier New, monospace",
                    size=16,
                    # color="#ffffff"
                    ),

            })
        ]

annotations = list(fig.layout.annotations) + extra_annotations
fig.update_layout( annotations=annotations)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response that's very helpful, is there a way to update the x axis for the top two subplots so that they're blank? As I wanted to avoid duplicating unnecessary detail. I've updated my initial post with pics of what I'm trying to achieve, I'm fairly sure I was able to do this when I used R

Comment: I'll have a look. I've to warn you that then the xticks (and yticks) on the subplots could differ.